# make socket response as hex byte

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I response as buffer binary?

```
sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);
        let response = new Buffer("0000", "base64");
        setTimeout(function() {
            sockets.forEach(function(sock, index, array) {
                sock.write(response);
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
```

because now I am getting hex byte: 30303030

Answer (score 0):

yes, you get 30303030 because the char "0" is 0x30 in hex. try

```
Buffer.from("00aabbcc","hex")
```

or

```
Buffer.from([0x0,0xaa,0xbb,0xcc])
```

and please don't use new Buffer() it is unsafe and deprecated. 
https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-buffer-deprecation-in-node-js-10/